# Change wedge buffers from arcs to slices

Tags: qgis, buffer, geometry-generator

I recently updated QGIS to 3.34.0 from 3.22.5 and noticed the program renders wedge buffers differently from what I'm used to. They appear as arcs around a point such as

[image]

Instead of as slices of a pie like

[image]

Projects which I made with the previous edition are unchanged when I open them, it's only new projects. My code in geometry generator is

```
wedge_buffer(center:=$geometry,azimuth:=0,width:=("Orange"*360)/"Total",outer_radius:=2*log10("Total"/.6))
```

Is there a setting that would change the arcs to wedges?

Comment: What is the geometry type of your geometry generator? Maybe you didn't change to "polygon"?

Comment: Your expression works well for me, producing the results in the second screenshot. Show us a screenshot with your Geoemtry Generator settings.

Comment: Erik is correct